# Hiding page elements using jQuery animations without it leading to display: none;

Tags: jquery, uploadify, fade

I'm using the Uploadify plugin to upload files to my server, and I want the upload form to fade away and the progress bar to fade in once the upload initializes. Only problem is, Uploadify stops working when the upload form gets the `display: none;` property, which all jQuery fading effects seem to lead to after their duration.

I tried doing:

```
$('#upload-form').css('opacity', 0);
```

which works. The upload continues after the form is hidden, but it doesn't have a fading effect.

Any solution? Thanks!

Comment: Once, somewhere i have read that, `You cannot trick FLASH with CSS`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [jQuery.animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

```
$('#upload-form').animate({
    opacity: 0
}, 'slow');
```

Answer (score 2):

This may be a workaround:

```
$('#upload-form').fadeTo(1000, 0.01, function() {
    $(this).css('opacity', 0);
});
```